# Mapping oracle XMLTYPE with openjpa 2.2.2

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, openjpa

Entity java code:

```
 @Column(name="XMLCOL", columnDefinition="XMLTYPE") 
    private String xmlcol;

public String getXmlcol() {
    return xmlcol;
}

public void setXmlcol(String xmlcol) {
    this.xmlcol = xmlcol;
}
```

Table Column datatype:

```
XMLCOL   PUBLIC.XMLTYPE STORAGE BINAR
```

Every time i am getting xml data as NULL. Not able to fetch the data.

Tried `@ColumnTransformer(read = "to_clob(columnName)", write = "?")` but not working. Also getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "com.javawebtutor.Supplier.xmlcol" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "varchar".  Column details:
Full Name: Supplier.XMLCOL
Type: unknown(2009)
Size: 2000
Default: null
Not Null: false
```

Adding persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Supplier</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
              <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After changing ojdbc6.jar Issue got resolved.. Used 11g ojdbc6.jar instead of 12c